# Locking Eclipse Icon to Launcher

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit. I recenetly downloaded eclipse kepler from their website and it runs fine and all that. But one thing i noticed was that it was a downloaded archive file, and it wasn't installed on the system. When I launch the icon to the launchbar, it does not open it the next time. And upon restart, the icon is gone. Kindly help me out here. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out after sometime. In order to do so, make a desktop file of the same name of the executable file for example eclipse.desktop in this case. Type the following in the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version = 1.0
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Used to run C++
Exec= "Path to the executable of the application"
Icon="Path to the icon of the application"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Save the file and then right click on it and click Properties. Go to the Permissions tab and then check allow executing file as program.

Launch eclipse from it and then pin it to the Launcher. Done and Done.

Comment: What do you mean by "Launch eclipse from it". The file is executable but one cannot execute it from the command line. Presumably there is a way to get the Launcher to launch it. How?

Comment: It means that when you check 'allow executing file as a program', you can launch eclipse, as in, open eclipse from that file. Once you run eclipse, you can right click it's icon on the Launcher and then pin it.

Comment: @RayKiddy Have you tried doubleclicking it on nautilus? The whole idea of having a .desktop is to run it from the launcher, not from command line.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 with Eclipse Mars (4.5.0) and did not need to perform any of the above. All I did was:

1. Download Eclipse
2. Uncompress:`tar -zxvf eclipse-java-mars-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`
3. Copy to /opt directory: `sudo mv ./eclipse /opt`
4. Open Nautilus and navigate to `/opt/eclipse`
5. Run Eclipse by double clicking `eclipse`
6. Right-click on Eclipse in the launcher and select `Lock to Launcher`

Eclipse is now in my launcher and works as expected.

Comment: "Lock to Launcher" is not offered, depending on UI versions, Eclipse version, Ubuntu version

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when rolling back from Mars to Luna on Ubuntu 16.04.
Turns out there was a dirty file left by Mars in:

```
~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

created when I had locked Mars to the panel the first time and pointing to the deleted Mars folder.
Problem solved by:

1. Quitting the instance of Luna.
2. Removing the said file.
3. Starting Luna from command line.
4. Right mouse click on the panel icon -> Lock to
   Launcher.
5. Quit Luna again.

Naxt time it should start by clicking the panel icon.

The advantage of re-creating automatically the desktop file this way is that Eclipse is launched with the correct parameters, i.e.:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar ...
```

Comment: this fixed my issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (using Unity)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is nearly an year old and I cannot find a relevant question in the SO, I am adding my own answer which worked for me :-)

The easiest way is to create a shortcut to the downloaded eclipse in the /usr/bin directory and pin it to the launcher.

```
# cd $ECLIPSE_DIRECTORY
# ln -s eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse
```

And  then launch the eclipse like you normally do. Then Right Click on the Eclipse icon in the launcher and Click on Lock To Launcher in the context menu properties.

Comment: Were you able to add the soft link of eclipse to `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:
Start your App and on Launcher menu click right-mouse button on your app and choose "Lock to Launcher"

Answer (score -1):

The most simple and effective way.

Go to **usr/share/applications** folder and find Eclipse icon.
Right click on it and select copy to desktop.

Thats it. Now double click on this icon and it will run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please take some time and complete [Welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.